# How does Payflow Gateway Recurring Billing handle monthly billing with a start date near the end of the month?

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

If the start date is set to the 29th, 30th, or 31st, and the PAYPERIOD is set to MONT (monthly), what happens on (for example) Jan 31st? Is the next billing period set to Feb 28th (or 29th on a leap year)? Should I just bump all recurring payments starting on those 3 days to the 1st of the next month?